# How can I make a list of all the matching patterns to the Regex objects using Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I just started coding and I came across a problem: I have to find the number of streaks (receiving head or tail for a three or more times in a row) when the coin is flipped for a given times. This is what I got so far:

```
    import random, re
    lst=[]
    def coin_flip(b):
         for i in range(b):
              a=random.randint(0,1)
              if a==0:
                   lst.append("H")
              else:
                   lst.append("T")
    def check_for_streak(l):
         string="".join(l)
         Head=[]
         Tail=[]
         Head=re.compile(r'(H){3,}').findall(string)
         Tail=re.compile(r'(T){3,}').findall(string)
         return "The number of streaks is "+str(len(Head)+len(tail))
```

So the problem here is that I expected the lists Head and Tail to contain the streak of H or T rather than the "H" and "T" in a streak itself ( Head=["HHHHH","HHHH",...] instead of Head=["H","H",...]) but it does not seem to be the case. Is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: Try re.split. should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your regex, use `(H{3,})` instead of `(H){3,}`:

```
import random, re

def coin_flip(b):
    lst=[]
    for i in range(b):
        if random.randint(0,1):
            lst.append("H")
        else:
            lst.append("T")
    return lst

def check_for_streak(l):
     string="".join(l)

     head = re.compile(r'(H{3,})').findall(string)
     tail = re.compile(r'(T{3,})').findall(string)
     print(string)
     print(head)
     print(tail)
     return "The number of streaks is "+str(len(head)+len(tail))

lst = coin_flip(100)

print( check_for_streak(lst) )
```

Prints (for example):

```
THTTTTHHHTHHHHHHHTHTTTTHHHTHTHTTHTHTTTTTTHHTTTTHTTHTHTTTHTHTTHHHTHTHHHTHHHTTTTHHTTHTHHHTTTHHTTTHHHHT
['HHH', 'HHHHHHH', 'HHH', 'HHH', 'HHH', 'HHH', 'HHH', 'HHHH']
['TTTT', 'TTTT', 'TTTTTT', 'TTTT', 'TTT', 'TTTT', 'TTT', 'TTT']
The number of streaks is 16
```